# Excel sheet view in c# application

Tags: c#, excel

I'm making an appliciation in c# that let view a specific sheet of a large excel file. The intention is to see the sheet inside my application. It is not the intention to open the entire excel or view all sheets. Is there a way to open this? I can, if necessary, print the excel files to a pdf, if this is more useful? Can I print the Excel file to an image and then show it in a picture box? Then it is also the difficulty to show the right sheet. You should not be able to do anything with that opened excel sheet, only view it.

[image: IMG1]

Thanks in advance,
Dries

Comment: What type of C# app? Winforms? Webforms? MVC? Mobile?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to print to pdf and show it. Is that the answer you looking for? If not please clarify your question, what you have tried and what didn't worked